# Read text from file and rearrange the columns?

Tags: python, matrix

I have a text file which has content:

```
A;B;C;D
a;b;c;d
```

I am reading the file in python and wants to rearrange the column such as-

```
B;C;D;A
b;c;d;a
```

I have tried reading column -

```
file = open('add.txt','r')
text = file.read()
column1 = x[0] for x in text
```

But this didn't help. So I need a way to convert it.

Comment: You want just to print them in this order ?

Comment: Yes. It will be a specific order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the csv module to read your file into lists, then is just a matter of re-indexing the list order.

```
import csv
list_variable = []
with open("file.txt") as add_txt:
    reader = csv.reader(add_txt, delimiter =';')
    for line in reader:
        line += [line.pop(0)]
        list_variable.append(line)
```

Comment: Hi instead of printing it I want to assign it to a list or variable.

Comment: @AvinashKumar the new edited answer will give you a list of lists

Comment: Thanks. This helped me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tuple/iterable unpacking to do this

```
with open('add.text','r') as f:
for line in f:
    cols = line.strip().split(';')
    col1, col2, col3, col4 = cols
    print col2, col3, col4, col1

#output
B C D A
b c d a
```

Comment: ----> 3        col1, col2, col3, col4 = cols
      4         print col2, col3, col4, col1

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 1)

Comment: @AvinashKumar I have updated my answer. It will work now.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the `csv` module as one answer suggested:

```
with open('add.txt', 'r') as file:
    text = file.read()
    result = []
    for line in text.splitlines():
        cols = line.split(';')
        cols = cols[1:] + [cols[0]]
        result.append(cols)

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[['B', 'C', 'D', 'A'], ['b', 'c', 'd', 'a']]
```

Comment: Hi instead of printing it I want to assign it to a list or variable.